# How do i solve this difference of two integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

$$f(x) =  \root^3 \of{3x^2  -  2x^3}$$

$$f:R \rightarrow R$$

$$I_n= \int_0^1x^n f(x)dx$$

Prove that $I_1-I_2=\frac{1}{8}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\int (f(x) + g(x))\ dx = \int f(x) dx + \int g(x) dx$ we have :
$$
I_1 - I_2 = \int_0^1 f(x)(x-x^2) dx = \int_0^1 \root^3 \of{3x^2 -2x^3}(x-x^2) dx \overset{(*)}{=}\frac16 \int_0^1 \root^3 \of{t}\ dt
$$
$(*)$
Letting $t = 3x^2 - 2x^3$, $dt = (6x - 6x^2)\ dx$. (The bounds don't change).

Can you finish ?